# If I increase the number of motors in a parallel circuit, will my current increase?

Tags: current, brushless-dc-motor, lipo

I am new to electronics, and am looking to build my own quadcopter. Before I purchase anything, I want to make sure I can get an appropriate battery to power the motors.

The battery I am looking at is a lithium polymer 3s (11.1V), 5200mAh, with a maximum discharge capacity of 30c.

The motors I am looking at are DXW A2212 DC, 3 phase brushless motors. I believe the maximum current load will be no greater than 20 amps, and the max efficiency current is at 10 amps. Assuming that there will be a constant current of 20 amps being drawn, and I add 3 more motors (4 in total), what will happen to the current drawn from the battery?

I know that the current in parallel is split up, so will my overall current drawn increase?

[image]

In the example above 2A is split up. If I reverse this, and have 20 amps * 4 (as 4 motors in parallel to each other, each drawing 20 amps), would I be drawing 80 amps from the battery? This would be logical, but I don't know if it is how motors work.

I hope this made some sense.

Comment: You should consult with experienced quadcopter pilots and builders on a user forum, not seek an answer from first principles here as you are missing any information about *typical* power requirements and utilization for flight.   Also, start small, by which I mean *tiny* - say 15-20 grams all up.  Make your learning mistakes on something with fewer consequences.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think that would be a good idea. I have bought some single phase dc motors to start with, and I will be setting them up in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put two identical resistors in parallel, the resulting resistance is 1/2 of each resistor. Therefore, twice as much current will be drawn from the power source.

So, yes, if you put four motors in parallel, they will try to draw quadruple the current as one. (Actually, not quite 4x as the internal resistance of the battery will drop the voltage to some degree.)

Comment: I thought that would be the case, thanks!

Comment: I am actually thinking about connecting the motors in series, but as they are 3 phase DC motors, I am not sure if that would work well...

Comment: @Angus I don’t recommend putting motors in series as their current draw is not continuous and so they may interfere with each other. In any case, if you put 4 motors in series, they will need 4x the voltage so you end up with the same number of batteries as the parallel case, just configured differently. There is no free lunch.

Comment: You raised a good point @DoxyLover, I thought about this, and it will be best to have motors in parallel. My concern was also lifted, as the load of the motors will be shared, so the current will be split, so in the end having 1 motor drawing 20A will be the same as 4 motors drawing 5A if the load stays the same.